# Using Socket.io with Swift or SwiftUI socket listener

Tags: swift

I would like to know if there is a way that we can have multiple arguments in a socket.io listener

The default example showing on the socket.io reported shows this

```
socket.on("currentAmount") {data, ack in
    guard let cur = data[0] as? Double else { return }
    
    socket.emitWithAck("canUpdate", cur).timingOut(after: 0) {data in
        if data.first as? String ?? "passed" == SocketAckValue.noAck {
            // Handle ack timeout 
        }

        socket.emit("update", ["amount": cur + 2.50])
    }

    ack.with("Got your currentAmount", "dude")
}
```

I would like to do something like this

```
socket.on("currentAmount") {data, arg2, arg3 in
    guard let cur = data[0] as? Double else { return }

    // Do something here    
}
```